# Auto Reconnect in WCF Service

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, client-server

I have a server which gets receives data from multiple systems, add them to the database and updates another application (client) with the latest received data. This client (both run in the same computer) presents the data in an organized form and do some processing on it. Moreover, it can perform queries in the database using the server. So it uses a function from the server to get historical data.

For this communication I am using WCF, and the server is declared as follows in the .config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="ServiceName">
        <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" contract="IServiceName">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:5050/msservice"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

The client uses the following configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="00:02:00" openTimeout="00:02:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:02:00" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxConnections="10" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false"/>
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign"/>
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:5050/msservice" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IService" contract="Server.IService" name="NetTcpBinding_IService">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost"/>
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

When the client creates the service (Connects to Server) it uses a service function called Subscribe, which includes the client in servers connected clients list. When a new data arrives, it raises an event in all clients.

However, after some inactivity of the client (because it does not send messages to server regularly, even though the opposite occurs in a very high frequency), it goes into faulted state. When this occurs, every client call of a server functions raises an exception.

I would like to, either on server side or client side, reconnect automatically whenever the channel is down in order to guarantee that the client still receives the messages from client, and that the function call from the client is executed by the server.

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Load balancer closes idle connections after 1 minute. So if you want to keep the connection alive then there should be always some communication

1) First option is to invoke an operation every minute.

2) If this is not possible, then

- Enable reliable messaging on the binding and the WCF infrastructure will handle it.
- You can configure the inactivityTimeout and the receiveTimeout to ensure that the channel is kept open.
- Both timeouts must be set otherwise if either one expires, the channel becomes faulted.
- After reliable session configuration, if the connection becomes idle, WCF will generate traffic to keep it open.